# Django: Check if connection is secure from template?

Tags: django, ssl

I want to check if my site is running under HTTPS from within my template so that I can conditionally add S's to the HTTPs of my external javascript libraries (namely, jQuery). How can I do that?

Comment: This can also be handled by middleware: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566112/how-to-implement-httpsssl-middleware-in-django/37599845#37599845](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566112/how-to-implement-httpsssl-middleware-in-django/37599845#37599845)

Comment: @LakeDupin That middleware is for forwarding to HTTPS which is a bit more than I was asking for, but inside lies the secret sauce: `request.is_secure()`. However, that's [already been posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4360699/65387).

Comment: LakeDupin lol =)  Cool I'm happy you have an answer that works!!!  Just wanted to offer a middleware solution if that was more fitting for someone else in the future.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if Google did this at the time I asked this question, but they now recommend you add the library via

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The `//` will use whatever scheme you are currently using -- no extra code or conditionals required.

Answer (score 14):

If your resources are hosted on the same machine as you are serving requests from, it may not need to specify a url scheme at all:

```
<script src="/static/js/myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will use the same protocol (http or https) and server as the request to the original page.

Edit 2 (2016):

If you're accessing a resource on another server, the best solution now (as [pointed out by mpen below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13728686/260491)) is to use the relative URL scheme:

```
<script src="//media.example.com/static/js/myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will automatically connect to the server using http or https depending on the connection to the current page.

Note that this may cause [some problems](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5a-missing-schema-double-download/) if you need to support old browsers.

Edit: Alternatively, if you really need the info in your template for some reason, you can [add the request context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request), and use a [RequestContext](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) in your views. This places a `request` variable in your template context, which gives you access to the `HttpRequest` object. You can then test if the request is secure by checking the value of `request.is_secure`

For example:

```
<script src="http{% if request.is_secure %}s{% endif %}://media.example.com/static/js/myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I am using relative URLs, but Google is hosting my jQuery... not so helpful ;) Your alternative solution looks viable... hope it works on my server.

Comment: This is the most upvoted answer in this thread, but I think the relative scheme will be way more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13728686/217649

Comment: @Pieter yup, you're right -- that's a better approach now. I don't believe that was as widely supported in 2010 as it is today.

Answer (score 6):

Check the request in the View with [is_secure](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure)(), and send it to the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...:) {% if request.is_secure %}{% endif %} using this we can check https in django

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the `{% static %}` template tag (in Django >= 1.4) which can be configured to host media files on a separate domain or server. This will do away with your is_secure problem.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:templatetag-staticfiles-static

Answer (score 0):

for checking the connection scheme, you can use the `request.scheme` attribute

```
{% if request.scheme == "http" %}

{% elif request.scheme == "https" %}

{% endif %}
```