# How to implement Https(SSL Middleware) in Django

Tags: django, ssl, django-middleware

I am a newbie in Django and web development. I want to implement 
   [Exactly this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454021/how-to-implement-a-https-login-page-in-a-web-application), but in django. I have searched many blogs and questions, nowhere was i able to find,exactly how to implement this. The [SSL Middleware Django](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/), is something i couldnt grasp very well. If that is the solution, can anyone please tell me how to implement it?

Is the question clear ? or do i need to add a few things, please comment i will make the necessary changes.Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

P.S: I have added the ssl certificate on the server. So that is taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the middleware class to the list of middleware in your settings.py and follow the instructions for your views as directed in the snippet. [Here's the documentation guide to middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/middleware/).

Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example middleware that redirects to the SSL site if HTTP is used:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.shortcuts import redirect

  #Require SSL com only. If we get anything else, redirect to https /
class RequireSSL(object):
  def process_request(self, request):
    assert isinstance( request, HttpRequest )
    if not request.is_secure():
      return redirect( 'https://%s/' % request.get_host() )
```

Then inside your settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'website.middleware.require_ssl.RequireSSL',
    ...
]
```